# Google Apps Script withSuccessHandler is running before function fully executes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I have two files in an Apps Script project.  One is a .gs file acting as a "server" and one is a .html file containing JavaScript as per Google's Apps Script guidelines.

Everything has been going swimmingly for the first 40 hours of development on this project.  I have the following line of code outside of any function, in between two   tags in the .html file:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(setSheetData).getSheetData();
```

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)

According to the documentation, getSheetData() should first execute in the .gs file, and return a value that is then passed into setSheetData which exists in the .html file.

Server file:

```
  function getSheetData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = activeSheet.getName();
  var sheetVals = activeSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  return [sheetName, sheetVals];
}
```

Html file:

```
function setSheetData(data) {
    alert(data);
    sheetName = data[0];
    sheetData = data[1];
    headers = sheetData[0];
    document.getElementById('sheetLook').innerHTML = 'Looking at sheet: ' + sheetName;
}
```

**How I know it is a matter of execution speed:**
Currently the alert() call just prints out null.  The sheet it is drawing from contains 4 rows of data.  However, all other things remaining the same, if I simply am looking at a sheet with 0-1 rows of data, it correctly alerts the entire data vals.

Inside of getSheetData() if I add Logger.log(sheetVals) it correctly logs the entire sheet's data regardless of size.  The issue is that the successhandler is executing **before** it has time to evaluate.

Comment: Questions that look fo help on debugging code should include a [mcve]. While your question include code, the HTML is incomplete as it doesn't show the tags that enclose `google.script.run...` statement.

Comment: Does you data have a restricted type in it.  Take a look at [Parameters & Return Values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Possible cause(s):

- Illegal return values in rows 3-4 of data
- No `active` sheet is present.

#### Solution:

- Avoid returning illegal values like `Date` objects. Or `JSON.stringify()` them before returning to client.
- `getSheetByName` or number instead of getting it by `active`ness.

#### References:

- [google.script.run § myFunction § return](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...))

Comment: Marking this as correct however there is an even simpler solution if you'd like to edit your comment.  The issue was indeed illegal return values (Dates).  Rather than stringifying things, you can simply call getDisplayValues() instead of getValues() on the range.