# GoogleAppScript TABLE WEB, I can't show table values ​when it has date format values

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, web-applications

I would like to know how I can bring the values ​​from the spreadsheet to the table when I have a column with the date format.

Every time I have to update the web table I  have to go into the spreadsheet and format the column as plain text. for the script shows the data in the web table

Is something wrong with the function?

Link Exemple Sheets: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OokFvWCx-ROkhaLP1nYQPDAu8zgCTeizHHq0ABnBL0A/edit#gid=0

```js
function pegarTabelaEstoque(){
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OokFvWCx-ROkhaLP1nYQPDAu8zgCTeizHHq0ABnBL0A/edit#gid=0"
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Página1");
  var dadosTabela = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 3).getValues();
  //Logger.log(dadosTabela);
  
  return dadosTabela;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
   
    <base target="_se">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    
  <div class= "container">

    
      <table class="striped centered ajuste" id="tab">
               <thead >           
                 <tr>
                 
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>NOME</th>
                  <th>DATA</th>
                                   
                 </tr>
               </thead>
                <tbody id="coportoTabela">
                
                </tbody>
      </table>

  
  </div> <!-- Fecha Conatainer -->
 
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script> 
   <script>
   
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
            
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(gerarTabela).pegarTabelaEstoque();
         
      });
      
      function gerarTabela(dataArray){
        var tcorpo =  document.getElementById("coportoTabela");    
         
         dataArray.forEach(function(r){
         
         var linha = document.createElement("tr");
         
         var coluna1 = document.createElement("td");
         coluna1.textContent = r[0];
         var coluna2 = document.createElement("td");
         coluna2.textContent = r[1];
         var coluna3 = document.createElement("td");
         coluna3.textContent = r[2];
         
         linha.appendChild(coluna1);
         linha.appendChild(coluna2);
         linha.appendChild(coluna3);
                      
         tcorpo.appendChild(linha); 
         
         });      
      
      }

   </script>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script withSuccessHandler is running before function fully executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57274328/google-apps-script-withsuccesshandler-is-running-before-function-fully-executes)

Comment: Pass the Date()s as strings that you can use with the Date() constructors.

Comment: How can I pass the new Date () as a string?

Comment: new Date().toString() , that way?

Comment: Here's one way `var today="Sep 7, 2019".

Comment: the problem is the format : Sat Sep 07 2019 21:16:13 GMT-0300 (BRT)

Comment: I did it this way, I don't know, if it was the correct function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return ["'"+day, month,year ].join('/').toString();
}

Comment: @Fragos As said in the duplicate question, 1.use `var dateAsString = JSON.stringify(dateObject)` 2.See comment in the duplicate question  `getDisplayValues()`